# Can we use first form of verb after helping verb?

Tags: verbs

Can we say "my hobby is read book"? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the sense that you mean it, no.

Your example contains *is read*. If *read* is the base form (as your question implies), this is not grammatical. [As it happens *read* is also the past participle of *read* (pronounced differently: the base form sounds the same as *reed*, but the past participle sounds the same as *red*), so *is read* can be grammatical; but it is passive, so something *every night a book is read* makes sense. But I don't think this is what you meant.]

What I think you are trying to say is *my hobby is reading books*. Various things can follow *is*: a noun or noun phrase, an adjective or adjectival phrase, an adverb or adverbial phrase; but not a verb phrase. The *-ing* form of verbs acts like a noun, or introduces a clause which acts like a noun phrase. So *reading books* acts like a noun phrase, and can follow *My hobby is*.